# Continuously read from file and do an action

Tags: java, user-interface, file-io

I want to continuously read from a text file, and change the color of a box I have shown on the canvas when a certain line is read (the text file is going to be constantly updating). Right now, I have a green square drawn on the canvas and three "test" lines in the text file, and when it reaches the third line of the text file I would like to change the the square to Red.

Here is my code, from two files (myCanvas.java and myFileReader.java). Any point in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

```
public class myCanvas extends Canvas{

    public myCanvas(){
    }

    public void paint(Graphics graphics){
        graphics.setColor(Color.green);
        graphics.fillRect(10, 10, 100, 100);
        graphics.drawRect(10,10,100,100);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        myCanvas canvas = new myCanvas();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Live GUI");
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(canvas);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        myFileReader read = new myFileReader();
        read.readFromFile();
        if(myFileReader.strLine == "This is the third line."){
        //change color
        }

}



public class myFileReader{
    public static String strLine;

public void readFromFile() 
{
    try{
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\sample.txt");
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        while (true){
            strLine = br.readLine();
            if(strLine == null) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        }
    catch (Exception ex){
        System.err.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: How do I update the color from inside the main method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way you can do it without much changes to your code.

1. Create a local variable in your `MyCanvas` class called `currentColor` of type `Color`. FYI, the convention in Java is to have class names start with a capital letter.
2. Update your `paint()` method to set the color of the rectangle to the new variable `currentColor`, instead of the static green value.
3. In your main method, you can do `canvas.currentColor = <new color here>;` and then `canvas.repaint()`. The `repaint()` function call will erase the canvas and redraw it using your `paint()` function.

I don't think your `FileReader` will work well with a file that's constantly being modified though.

Comment: Awesome, thats exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a counter and increment it each time you read a line. When the counter reaches the third line use an if statement to do your task

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
1.Use BreakIterator class, with its static method getLineInstance(), 
  this will help you identify every line in the file.

2. Create an HashMap with the colour as Key, and its RGB as Value.

3. Parse every word in the line, which is obtained from
   BreakIterator.getLineInstance().

4. Compare it with the Key in the HashMap, 
   if the word in the line happens to match the Key in
   the HashMap, then colour the box with the Value of the Key.
```